# Can we recite "shehakol nihyeh bidvaro" over coffee and tea?

Tags: halacha, blessing, food

Can we recite "shehakol nihyeh bidvaro" over coffee and tea ? If not, what is the appropriate bracha ?

Comment: http://www.halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Bracha_on_Coffee_and_Tea

Comment: @Danno very useful and interesting !! never knew that before.

Comment: @Danno It seems that this would be the answer. Why don't you expand on the contents and make it an answer. "The Panim Meiros has put forth a seemingly strong halachic argument and brought many proofs to support his case[16]. However, he ends off his responsa by stating that the beracha on coffee and tea still remains a Shehakol as this has been the minhag of the Jews for as long as he can remember and the minhag is not going to change, therefore, he too only recited a Shehakol on coffee and tea."

Comment: @sabbahillel it isn't my work, nor do I have anything to add to it. I chafe at posting pure single links and summaries (or excerpts) as an answer.

Comment: @mil can you explain your reasoning as to why one wouldn't say this beracha?

Comment: @bondonk I never said one shouldn't say this bracha, I was just asking if it's the right bracha.

Comment: @mil it would still strengthen the question if you stste the הוה אמינה

Comment: @Danno You chafe at posting summaries (or excerpts) as an answer. But you surely would want to support your own answer with sources; which is really not so different.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/65120